# Search for text within a range of cells in Excel using an IF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to search for text within a range/array of cells in Excel.

Right now I have a working formula to search for 2 non-printing characters in a single cell, but I need to search multiple cells on the same row.

What is working: `=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(" ",$H2))),"Non-printing character",IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(" ",$H2))),"Non-printing character","OK"))`

What I want to do is search $H2:$Q2 and if a non-printing character is contained anywhere within $H2:$Q2, I want cell G2 to display "Non-printing character." If a non-printing character is not found, I want G2 to display "OK."

Any ideas?

Comment: Turns out I don't need a nested statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't need to nest, and I just need to find one non-printing character within a range, I was able to use the following formula:

=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(" ",CONCATENATE($H2,$I2,$J2,$K2,$L2,$M2,$N2,$O2,$P2,$Q2)))),"Non-printing character","OK")

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension of your posted formula to test multiple cells:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(" ",TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,H2:Q2)))),"Non-printing character",IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(" ",TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,H2:Q2)))),"Non-printing character","OK"))
```

We replaced:

```
$H2
```

with:

```
TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,H2:Q2)
```

Comment: Thank you! The TEXTJOIN function is very helpful.